# Android Fragment Webview Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, webview, android-fragments

I could use some help identifying an issue in my code regarding fragments and webviews. I tried implementing some of the solutions in the other threads unsuccessfully. I've tested this same fragment being replaced without the webview being created inside and there is no leak. Any ideas? If not, can anyone pose an alternate solution?

Here's my webview fragment:

```
public class CustomWebViewFragment extends PageFragment
{

private LinearLayout mWebContainer;
private WebView mWebView;


/**
 * public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
 * Bundle savedInstanceState)
 */
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    //If I comment this line out, there is no memory leak
    mWebView = new WebView(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()); 

    return v;
}


/**
 * public void onDestroy()
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mWebView != null)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        mWebView.destroy();
        mWebView = null;
    }
}
```

}

Here's how I'm changing fragments:

```
@Override
public void onNavSelected(String page)
{
    if (page != null && !page.equals(""))
    {
        System.gc();
        if (page.equalsIgnoreCase(GlobalConstants.PAGE_1))
        {
            mCurrent = getFragment(); // Creates a new fragment
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment, mCurrent).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank"). That fixed my memory leak!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
//If I comment this line out, there is no memory leak
mWebView = new WebView(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

&

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mWebView != null)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        mWebView.destroy();
        mWebView = null;
    }
}
```

To

```
mWebView = new WebView(getActivity());
```

&

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // null out before the super call
    if (mWebView != null)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        mWebView = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: can you add the memory leak logging statements to you question,  it will help narrow things down.

Comment: The webview was only exasperating a leak somewhere else in the application. This is the correct way to properly destroy a webview. Marking as answer.

Comment: I think, you meant onDestroyView(), not onDestroy(). Otherwise there still can be memory leak. According to fragment lifecycle there can be situation when onCreateView() got called multiple times, but onDestroy() only once.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the mem leak was caused by using the app context instead of activity context to create the webview.  This can easily be avoided by an xml layout (or using an activity context in the java constructor).